# Hausdorff distance between a sequence of sets and a limiting set

Tags: sequences-and-series, hausdorff-distance

I have a sequence of closed, compact sets $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. I know that both $A_n$ and $B_n$ are decreasing in $n$; i.e.

$n_1 > n_2 \implies A_{n_1}\subseteq A_{n_2} \text{ and } B_{n_1}\subseteq B_{n_2}$

I also know that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $A_n \rightarrow A$ for some set $A$ and $B_n \rightarrow \emptyset$.

Define the Hausdorff distance as:

\begin{equation}\nonumber
    d_H(X,Y) = \inf\{\epsilon \geq 0: X\subseteq (Y)_\epsilon\text{ and }Y\subseteq (X)_\epsilon\}
\end{equation}
where $(Z)_\epsilon$ represents the $\epsilon$-fattening of $Z$.

I want to show the following:

\begin{equation}\nonumber
d_H(A_n\setminus B_n,A) \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}

Can this be done? And how?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are $\{A_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and/or $\{B_{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ assumed to be compact?

Comment: $B_n\rightarrow \emptyset$ so that $\emptyset=(\emptyset)_\epsilon$ contains $B_n$ for some large $n$. Hence $B_n$ is empty set ?

Comment: They are assumed to be compact, yes.

Comment: @HKLee . I have the same trouble.... & if $X\ne \emptyset =Y$ then $d_H(X,Y)=\inf \,\emptyset .$

Comment: DanielWainfleet : I believe that OP wanted to say something like measure 0 set

Comment: Apologies, @HKLee you are right! I am unsure how to word this but my $B_n$ are going to a point in 2D Euclidean space whilst my $A_n$ are tending towards a region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B_n$ goes to a point $p$, then then $ \varepsilon$-ball
$B_\varepsilon (p)$ contains $B_n$ and
$d_H(A_n,A)<\varepsilon$ for $  n\geq N$ and some $N$.

$ A_n - B_n$ contains $ A_n - B_\varepsilon (p)$ and a closed
$\varepsilon$-tubular neighborhood of $A_n - B_\varepsilon (p)$
contains $A_n,\ A_n-B_n$. Hence $ d_H(A_n - B_n,A_n - B_\varepsilon
(p)) \leq \varepsilon$.

From triangle inequality $\ast$ of $d_H$, then

\begin{align*} d_H(A_n - B_n, A) &
\leq d_H(A_n - B_n,A_n-B_\varepsilon (p))  + d_H( A_n -
B_\varepsilon (p),A_n) +d_H(A_n,A) \\&\leq 2\varepsilon + d_H(A_n,A)
\\ &
 \leq 3 \varepsilon \end{align*}

We have a claim $\ast$ that $d_H$ satisfies triangle inequality :

If $d_H(X,Y)=r,\ d_H(Y,Z)=R$, then $(Y)_{r+\epsilon},\
(Y)_{R+\epsilon}$ contains $X,\ Z$ respectively.

Here $(X)_{r+\epsilon}$ contains $Y$ so that $(X)_{R+r+2\epsilon}$
contains $Z$. Similarly $(Z)_{R+r+2\epsilon}$ contains $X$ so that
$d_H(X,Z)\leq r+R$.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you! Yes, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Just a quick question; $A_n-B_n$ is not necessarily compact so how can the inequality be used? $d_H$ is only a metric on compact sets.

Comment: Ah okay I think I see... so the final step follows as $d_H(X,Z)\leq r+R+2\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, it is therefore true that $d_H(X,Z)\leq r+R$? Thank you!